# Rails: How to move array iteration from view to helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am looping through an array in view, it works, but when I tried to move the code to helper method, it did not work. The problem is I am not able to do <%= %> inside helper. Anybody could let me know how to fix the code?

**original view**

```
<% resources.each do |resource| %>
  <span class="label label-primary">
    <%= resource.name %>
  </span>
<% end %>
```

**updated view**

```
<%= print_resource resources%>
```

**resource_helper.rb**

```
def print_resource(resources)
  resources.each do |resource|
    text = resource.name
    clz = 'label label-primary'
    content_tag :span, text,clz
  end
end
```

Comment: it is return nothing right ?

Comment: @Thorin return like this `["<span class=\"label label-primary\">Update </span>", "<span class=\"label label-primary\">Delete</span>"']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do like this:

```
def print_resource(resources)
  html_values = ""
  resources.each do |resource|
    text = resource.name
    clz = 'label label-primary'
    html_values << (content_tag :span, text,clz)
  end
 html_values.html_safe
end
```

Comment: Thanks, it works for me. Could you let me know where I can learn things like this?